# Can a defendent travel overseas if served with a claim/summons to UK civil court?

Tags: united-kingdom, civil-law, small-claims-court, claims

If i have am served a claim form by the claimant, can I travel overseas?

Also, if I am overseas and receive the claim form whilst overseas, can I ignore it if I am not a citizen of the country which the claimant is from?

Answer (score 3):

> If i have am served a claim form by the claimant, can I travel overseas?

Yes

> Also, if I am overseas and receive the claim form whilst overseas, can I ignore it if I am not a citizen of the country which the claimant is from?

You can always ignore a civil summons - the likely effect is that judgement will be entered against you and the plaintiff can then take further action to enforce the judgement.

This can include having your property seized, garnisheeing your bank accounts or wages, or requiring you to attend court - failure to answer this summons is contempt and can lead to your arrest.

A judgement in a UK court can, subject to treaties, be enforced in foreign jurisdictions under the relevant local law.